# Nesting Select queries on select part of query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to nest two `SELECT` queries where the result of the "inner" query should be used to perform a multiplication for every tuple in the "outer" query.

The "inner" query should also access a field of the outer table (`tA.time` in this example).

Example:

```
  SELECT r1 * (SELECT r2 FROM tB WHERE time < tA.time)
    FROM tA
   WHERE xyz
GROUP BY xyz
```

**First question:** Is this possible in general?

**2nd question:** Is this possible using SQLite?

**3rd question:** Did I sketch the query the right way? I tried to run it that way but I couldn't make it work by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the subquery returns exactly one row, this should work on most SQL-compliant databases.  I have done similar things in SQLite and I suspect that it will work.

(If the subquery returns more than one row, there will be an error.  If it returns no rows, the result of the multiplication operation will be `NULL`.)

Comment: Thank you, I ensure getting only one row by setting LIMIT to 1 - I discovered that the sample data I used for testing was corrupted and couldn't give me the result I expected. Now everything is working fine!